# RISC-V 32bit Simulation with Spike failed with error

Tags: riscv, spike

I just got the source from github and built pk with 32bit option and ran spike with following command:

$ spike --isa=RV32 pk hello

I got the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  could not open pk

I used riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc to compile pk for the 32b RISC-V target processor as follows:

$ ../configure --prefix=$RISCV/riscv32-unknown-elf --host=riscv32-unknown-elf

The old spike program which I got from the first RISCV workshop(last January) works ok.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that spike can't find the pk. Try and provide an absolute path to the pk you compiled.

Spike assumes the pk is in a particular path relative to it. It's probably looking in ($RISCV/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/pk).

Comment: After I specify the absolute path to the pk, I got the following error:    assertion failed @ 0x000052bc: ntohl(hdr->magic) == FDT_MAGIC

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed.
The following code is a workaround:

```
mkdir -p $RISCV/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin
cp $RISCV/riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/pk $RISCV/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/pk
```